# how can I use async data from node api?

Tags: reactjs, api, asynchronous, axios

I'm fetching data from node.js.
So it's kinda late to get data...
I guess that's why my console says 'null' all the time :/
I tried several way to fix it, but it didn't help at all.

I did use UseState but it ended up saying 'null' data. My page kept saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

here's my react code:

```js
const Start = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const dataList = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      await axios
        .post('/api/getData')
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data.result);
          //  at this point, this console.log says what I exactly want.
          return (dataList = res.data.result);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    getData();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) return <div>...Loading...</div>;

  return (
    <div>
            
      {dataList.map((item, idx) => (
        <p>{item[0].dataName}</p>
      ))}
          
    </div>
  );
};
```

What should I do to use my data which was fetched from node.js?
the data is long, large JSON.

Answer (score 2):

To properly use React, you should keep data inside the state, so React's virtual DOM can properly render items according to that data (for your case).

Also, no need to chain `.then` whilst using `await`.

On another note, it is weird that you are using `axios.post` instead of `axios.get` for fetching the data, just a piece of friendly advice.

The reason why your `const dataList = null` never gets updated is because you are initializing it inside the render function, meaning every time the state gets updated (`setIsLoading`) your `dataList` gets reinitialized to `null`

```
const Start = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [dataList, setDataList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);

      const response = await axios.post('/api/getData');

      setIsLoading(false);
      setDataList(response.data.result);
    };

    getData();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>...Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {dataList.map((item, idx) => (
        <p>{item[0].dataName}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks for pointing my silly mistakes out! but it still got same problems :(